# How to determine correspondence between two lists of names?

Tags: algorithm

I have: 
1 million university student names and 
3 million bank customer names

I manage to convert strings into numerical values based on hashing (similar strings have similar hash values). I would like to know how can I determine correlation between these two sets to see if values are pairing up at least 60%?

Can I achieve this using ICC? How does ICC 2-way random work?

Please kindly answer ASAP as I need this urgently.

Comment: What do you mean by "pairing up to at least 60%"?  Do you mean at least 60% of the student names have matching customer names?  That 60% of the customer names have matching student names?  (Not possible unless you have a relaxed sense of "match"!)  Something else?  My guess is you don't have a problem in statistical analysis; it's a matter of coding an algorithm to compare two lists/sets/arrays.  If that's the case, SO might be a better venue for this question.

Comment: Could you say a little about why you need to do this? I'm having trouble thinking of a legitimate reason. Apologies if there is an obvious one I'm missing.

Comment: @onestop I want to clarify that you surely meant to write "statistically useful" rather than "legitimate" because I am sure you don't intend to impugn the motives of questioners visiting this site.

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches between the student and bank database? If you want partial matches (i.e. student named "Sam" matches bank customer "Samuel"), you've probably got more of a programming challenge than a statistics challenge.

Comment: Were the name lists lexicographically sorted? Will the corresponding hashes still be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of entity resolution etc is normally easy, but I am surprised by the hashing approach here.  Hashing loses information that is critical to entity resolution.  So, if possible, you shouldn't use hash, rather the original strings.

Assuming using original strings is an option, then you would want to do something like this:

List A (1M), List B (3M)

```
// First, match the entities that match very well, and REMOVE them.
for a in List A
  for b in List B
    if compare(a,b) >= MATCH_THRESHOLD   // This may be 90% etc
       add (a,b) to matchedList
       remove a from List A
       remove b from List B

// Now, match the entities that match well, and run bipartite matching
// Bipartite matching is required because each entity can match "acceptably well"
// with more than one entity on the other side
for a in List A
  for b in List B
    compute compare(a,b)
    set edge(a,b) = compare(a,b)
    If compare(a,b) < THRESHOLD // This seems to be 60%
       set edge(a,b) = 0

// Now, run bipartite matcher and take results
```

The time complexity of this algorithm is O(n1 * n2), which is not very good.  There are ways to avoid this cost, but they depend upon your specific entity resolution function.  For example, if the last name has to match (to make the 60% cut), then you can simply create sublists in A and B that are partitioned by the first couple of characters of the last name, and just run this algorithm between corresponding list.  But it may very well be that last name "Nuth" is supposed to match "Knuth", etc.  So, some local knowledge of what your name comparison function is can help you divide and conquer this problem better.